# The right way to setup notification system for a threaded comment system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm

I have build a custom commenting system for my app. Where by a user comes in and adds a comment and then others can reply to the comment. Over here only one table is created with the fields `body`,`created_at`, `updated_at`, `user`, `parent_id`. That being said, if a row has a `parent_id` that means its a child comment if not then its a parent comment.

Now I am trying to setup a basic notification system/area, where by users can keep track of the new comments. I am looking to setup something where users can see unread comments they received no matter if its a parent comment of child comment. Something similar to how github does.

So, how do I go about it? Initially i thought of adding one more field to the `Comment` table, saying `read`. Which would be a boolean and depending on if its true or not the notification will be shown. But the problem here is, i want all the users to be notified in the thread (all parent and child comments) about this new comment.

Now, what other approaches can I take to solve this problem?

Hope I didnt confuse you.

Comment: As you said, all the users have to be notified in the thread. So adding a field to the `comment` table won't work. You will want to set up a many-to-many association between `User` and `Comment` (for instance a `Notification` join model). Just my 2 cents, I am really interested in seeing more answers.

Comment: Yes I thought of setting up another model but not sure how to check for u read posts and efficiently handle the data at the same time

Comment: hum... maybe in your `ThreadsController#show` action (where the user actually see the thread and thus the new comments), you can destroy the notification: `current_user.notifications.where(thread: @thread).delete_all`

Comment: Well that's not the issue. The main question here is how do I make sure the notification reaches to all the people involved in the thread. If I create another table what sort of information it should have to make sure the right notification is created and updated. That is which users get it.

Comment: When a new comment is added to a thread, a notification is created for each person involved in the thread. `notifications` has a `user_id` and a `thread_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of my comments:

1. It's hard and unnecessary to judge if a comment is read or not. See in SO, if I leave a comment here, you'll see update when going to this page, but you still get notification on top left.
2. A notification can be judged read or not by JS, or by manually marked read which is simpler.
3. So, you don't need a is_read? field in Comment. Every comment is unread.

#### Firstly setup correct association in Comment.

Suppose you don't have a nested thread which is more complex and need HABTM association.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Comment'
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: 'parent_id'

  def related_comments
    parent.children - [self] if parent_id?
  end
end
```

#### Then use a callback/observer to process

Callback is for simplicity, Observer is preferred for this involves another Class.

```
  after_save :send_unread_notification, if: :parent_id?

  private
  # or better to send it to a backend job if necessary
  def send_unread_notification
    related_comments.each do |c|
      notification = Notification.new{
                       notifier: c.user,
                       message: 'You have unread comment',
                       sender:  'comment',
                       sender_id: c.id }
      notification.save!
    end
  end
```

#### Then create Notification class and UI

Leave out for simplicity.

Comment: well my parent and child comment setup is a little different. But yes the callback suggestion is helpful. I think I will do it that way. Thanks!